# Increment [ngStyle] attr using ngFor index?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically create several elements using ngFor and then set the top attribute depending on the amount drawn.

I'm wondering if there is a way to access the index of ngFor on the same div for ngStyle? i.e;

`<div class="row" *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index;" [ngStyle]="{'top': mrTop*i}" >`

If not, any suggestions how I can achieve something similar?

I would prefer to avoid adding another div like;

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index;">
  <div class="testCase" [ngStyle]="{'top': mrTop*i}">{{d}}</div>
</div>
```

(Although this doesn't work either)

I am wondering if there is a way to attach an event listener to the loop event so that behind the scenes I can increment the `mrTop` variable for each div drawn?

Anyway, I'm not sure how best to approach this and hoping for some help/advice.

[Plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pgr4vThVZpQyABdBrPoj?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have, but it doesn't seem to be working. Unless I've missed something - I included a plunk as an example which demonstrates the test case

Comment: I missed that link (as always if they are not emphasized) |-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `mrTop` variable is a string, you can't multiply it.

Try:

```
public mrTop = 10;
```

and then

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'top': mrTop*i + '%'}">
```

or

```
<div [style.top.%]="mrTop*i">
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several mistakes

```
'10%' * i // not valid number

public mrTop: 10; // defines mrTop as of type 10 which doesn't make sense
// it should be public mrTop= 10;
```

Ng style can look like

```
[ngStyle]="{'top': mrTop * i + '%'}"
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Y7izk0D10nKuEoSKRT2?p=preview)